# SharePoint Hosted App uploaded in App Catalog . App in Disabled Mode

Tags: sharepoint-addin, sharepoint-hosted-app, office-web-apps, azure, apps-development

I had uploaded my app package in "App Catalog" ,And I see it's status as below.Can any one do let me know ,How much time it will take to get enabled

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's SharePoint 2013 or 2016 it'll generally take a minute or less. Two minutes at the most. If it's slower you should check to see if any of your servers is low on available memory.

If it's SharePoint Online then it is less deterministic. It will generally take between one and ten minutes but, in rare cases, it can take an hour or more.